# What are possible reasons my SSRS report is throwing this error in the "Report Manager" view?

Tags: debugging, error-handling, reporting-services

My report was working just fine a few days ago, and i don't recall changing anything..

But I'm now getting this error when I run the report  in the "Report Manager" view.

```
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors
```

EDIT:

Ok so I did try the SPROC in SSMS like so:

```
exec prc_RPT_Quota_Info 17221
```

and it returns a proper result:

```
SurveyNumber    ID  HoursRemaining  FieldHours  FEDSurveyName   FieldEndDate    FieldBeginDate  SurveyStatusName    ProjectName ProjectManager  ClientName
17221   16226   -2195.75    NULL    j41881 - Burial Preferences Survey - States 2012-09-10 06:00:00.000 NULL    Complete    41881 Gibbs & Soell - Burial Preferences Survey Peter Gallagher BCC Public Affairs & Policy
```

any tips

Comment: Obviously, Dataset1's query no longer works. Try running it in the query editor of Dataset1 if it is a simple query and see what happens. Some of my queries are built from the ground up as strings and so can't be executed in the query editor; in this case I just run SQL Profiler against the database server and see what SQL is hitting the server.

Comment: I agree with Chris. I would also suggest coping out the query and testing it in SQL Server Management Studio. This would be required anyways if you are referencing a stored procedure. So, try testing the query outside of running the report and let us know what you find.

Comment: @ChrisLatta - when you say `query editor of Dataset1 if it is a simple query and see what happens` does this mean in MS Visual studio BIDS?  I will look into the SQL profiler! thanks

Comment: @Neil - thanks so much! I did try running it manually(but not by copying out the query from the BIDS, as i don't know how)  . It did work fine. i edited my post . thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Plainly, Dataset1's query isn't working. Firstly, check that the `Stored Procedure` radio button is selected in the Dataset Properties.

Running SQL Profiler and seeing what SQL is hitting the server might help.

Given that you have copied the query into SQL Server Management Studio and it works, it sounds like a permissions issue - that is, running it in SSMS under your account works, but it isn't working when the Reorting Services server runs it under its account.

Check the permissions of the Stored Procedure to see if the SSRS server account has the right permissions to execute the stored proc.

Comment: Thanks very much Chris .  So it turns out on my env. I don't have permission to access " SQL Server Profiler . I get "in order to run a trace against SQL Server you must be a member of sysadmin fixed server role or have the ALTER TRACE permission. "  But this is OK i think. I will try seeing the permissions issue . .If all else fails, will try re-doing the whole thing , i.e just starting over & usin a different name.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot I figured it out now..  so before, when I rt. click "dataset properties" , the 'query type' was  wrong. it was either "Text" radio button; or "Stored Proc"(the right one) and a wrong s-proc nam  .  sigh, i'm still learning

Comment: Glad you could figure out. There will always be things you will learn.